# Удалить коммит bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit

Сделал дураций коммит, и удалил 2 языковых файла. И всюду уже затянул git pull.

Можно как-то через сайт bitbucket.org удалить этот коммит из истории, чтобы репозиторий стал без этого коммита?

И что дает "Stop watching" в коммите?

Comment: можно, но не нужно.  В целом, есть такая чудная таблица http://i.stack.imgur.com/nxqyU.png где рассказано, что делать.

Comment: @KoVadim Почему не нужно? Я так понимаю через сам сайт bitbucket никак, надо через терминал get revert 2d83a76  (это номер id коммита - он не последний)

Comment: revert - это хороший вариант.

Comment: @KoVadim revert я так понял создает новый коммит закрывающий тот. А просто удалить абсолютно бестолковый коммит нельзя?

Comment: git reset по ходу осталось понять точную команду

Comment: Просто удалить коммит в середине истории нельзя. Можно только сделать rebase.

Comment: @KoVadim Благодарю за информацию. А такой вопрос значит 2 последних коммита можно командой git reset --hard HEAD~2  НО я ввожу эту команду у себя на сервере по shh получаю [master 66b66f3] delete Revert "на скале hidden"
 2 files changed, 6753 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
 create mode 100644 locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po  - НО НА САЙТЕ BITBUCKET коммиты видны

Comment: Нужно не забыть форсированно запушить. git push --force

Comment: @KoVadim Огонь спасибо, проблема решена, узнал много нового. Осталось разобраться что такое force и rebase) Еще раз благодарю за помощь (если хотите можете ответ составить)

Comment: Хотя конечно есть ещё момент... Я git reset 2 комита на сервере, потом git push --force удалил из репозитория эти комиты, а вот на локальном компе на винде В SourceTree они остались

Comment: на локальном компьютере нужно сделать git pull. Без этого никакие изменения не приедут к Вам (на самом деле изменения прилетают по git fetch, но потом все равно нужно делать либо мердж, либо ребейз, либо ресет). А SourceTree удалить и забыть.